# How to persist my notebooks and data in my Docker image/container

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I am new to Docker and I am confused about containers and images somehow. I want to sue Docker for Tensorflow development. All I need is to have an easy way to write Jupyter Notebooks and use GPU powered Tensorflow.

I have the latest Tensorflow Jupyter Python 3 Image already. I run the Image with

```
docker run --rm --runtime=nvidia -v -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3-jupyter
```

How can I make it so that my data when I work in that Image and add and edit my Jupyter Notebooks won't get lost after I exit the process. I know that Docker Images aren't meant to persist state but I am so new to this I just want something to work in with persistent data. Can someone help me guide me through this or point to a resource which will answer all my prayers?

I would also like to move some stuff into the Container that is going to be run so that I can access some custom Python libs because they contain some things that my Notebooks need to import!

Side questions:

`--rm` removes the container or whatever by default I run it without this flag still my data was lost

`-v` is for volumes? I tried with `-v Bachelor:/app` to mount a volume like so. It apparently doesn't make any difference. I don't know how to use the volume Bachelor that I created. Instead there are a multitude of unnamed volumes being created that are not usable whenever I run this

`-it` does also something no idea what

`-p` is the port number right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/):

> Volumes are the preferred mechanism for persisting data generated by and used by Docker containers

Example:

```sh
docker run --runtime=nvidia -v ${SOURCE_FOLDER}:${DEST_FOLDER} -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3-jupyter
```

Change `SOURCE_FOLDER` and `DEST_FOLDER` accordingly (**use absolute paths!**).

Now if you navigate to `localhost:8888` and create a notebook on `DEST_FOLDER`, it also should be available on `SOURCE_FOLDER`.

As for your side questions:

- --it runs a container in interactive mode. You generally add `/bin/bash` after the run command, so you can start an interactive bash session inside the container.
- --rm cleans the container after it exists.

Those options aren't really necessary for your use case. Just remember to use `docker ps` and `docker rm <ID>` to clean up your container after you're done.

Comment: source_folder and DEST_FOLDER are what exactly?

Comment: `SOURCE_FOLDER` is the folder in which you'd like to store your notebooks on your local machine. `DEST_FOLDER` is where it will be mounted inside your container.

Comment: can I mount an existing folder to the image/container or how can I move some of my local files into the DEST_FOLDER or SOURCE_FOLDER?